# I want to use one function on a series of input fields

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am wondering if anyone can point me to a topic or piece of code that might satisfy my requirements. Problem I have a function (at this stage just changing the color) that I want to run for each input field that has focus. I don't have any code to post so I will use pseudocode here to describe the problem:

```
input field1 id = aaaa
input field2 id = bbbb
input field3 id = cccc


function onFoc()
if input field has focus - 
document.getElementById("inputfieldwithfocus").style.background = "yellow";
```

I thought of using a switch with each field id in it and I have tried:

```
var hasfocus = $('a').is(':focus'); to no avail
```

My input fields have the onfocus attribute

```
<td><input type="text" name="aaaa" id="aaaa" onfocus="onFoc()" 
      size="15" value="<?php echo $aaaa;?>" maxlength="15"/>
```

post edit.... some of the code im using

```
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Lastname </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="p_name" id="p_name" class="inputt" 
onfocus="onFoc()" size="20" 
      maxlength="20" value="<?php echo $p_name;?>" />
      </td><td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
```

the function

```
            <script language="javascript">
            function onFoc() {
    for ( var input of document.getElementsByClassName('inputt') ) {
         if ( input.hasFocus() ) {
             //Do stuff here
             input.style.background = "yellow";
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not just use the CSS .focus selector? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:focus

Comment: thanks Jeff thats not a bad idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the fields a class, and select them via [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) or use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
function updateFocusedInputBackgroundsToYellow() {
    for ( var input of document.getElementsByClassName('inputs') ) {
         if ( input.hasFocus() ) {
             //Do stuff here
             input.style.background = "yellow";
         }
    }
}
```

Here's an example of querySelectorAll (Let's say your inputs are in a div with id of input-container):

```
function updateFocusedInputBackgroundsToYellow() {
    for ( var input of document.querySelectorAll('#input-container input') ) {
         if ( input.hasFocus() ) {
             //Do stuff here
             input.style.background = "yellow";
         }
    }
}
```

Ideally though, you want to just set the background yellow on focus, something like this would be better (On focus it sets it to yellow, on blur it sets it to none):

```
<td><input type="text" name="aaaa" id="aaaa" onfocus="this.style.background = 'yellow'" onblur="this.style.background = 'none'"
  size="15" value="<?php echo $aaaa;?>" maxlength="15"/>
```

Comment: not having much luck posting code here. i'll try something else

Comment: thank you @FrankerZ that last onfocus code worked a treat. simple but effective. ta.